# "Creating default object from empty value"

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to insert data to Database, but got the error `"Creating default object from empty value"` and still don't understand, this error come from?

**in My Controller**

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'amount' => 'required',
            'method' => 'required',
        ]);
        $payrolls = new Payroll();
        $payrolls->employee_id = auth()->user()->id;
        $payrolls->account_id = auth()->user()->id;
        $payrolls->employee_name = $request->get('employee_name');
        $payrolls->description = $request->get('description');
        $payrolls->account = $request->get('account');
        $payrolls->amount = $request->get('amount');
        $payrolls->method = $request->get('method');
        $payrolls->save();
        return response()->json(['created' => true]);
    }
```

Any help? Thanks......

Comment: You have typo in your code: $parolls = new Payroll(); It should be $payrolls

Comment: oh i see, thanks u..

Comment: @arm yeah there is typo in his code. z3r0 i  have updated your code, you can try with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @arm stated, you're having a typo in your code, which leads to the error you're getting.
The code below should make it working.
I would also suggest you to use `$request->input('****');` instead of dynamic variables like you're doing `$request->account;`

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'amount' => 'required',
        'method' => 'required',
    ]);

    $payrolls = new Payroll();
    $payrolls->employee_id = auth()->user()->id;
    $payrolls->account_id = auth()->user()->id;
    $payrolls->employee_name = $request->input('employee_name');
    $payrolls->description = $request->input('description');
    $payrolls->account = $request->input('account');
    $payrolls->amount = $request->input('amount');
    $payrolls->method = $request->input('method');
    $payrolls->save();

    return response()->json(['created' => true]);
}
```

You could also have a look at the `Payroll::create()`, which makes it easier to create a entry in the DB, instead of making a `new Payroll()`, and saving at the end. https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#mass-assignment

Comment: thanks so much for add more detail. but someone told me that my code is `bad`, can u guide to write a good code.

Comment: @z3r0 Well you code will be a lot more readable, and eventually look better, if you're looking into my suggestions